# iOS - Accessing variable declared in method A from method B in the same class

Tags: objective-c, methods

How do you do this? See my code example below:

```
- (void)methodA {
    ...
    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    ...
}

- (void)methodB {

    label1.text = "Label 1";
}
```

**EDIT:** Why I'm wondering this is because I can not set an instance variable to the class. Because I will not **know** when the class loads how many `UILabel`s I will need. It will be a different amount each time the class is loaded. So I will need to dynamically create these UILabels in a method and then be able to access these labels throughout the rest of the class in a convenient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to examine your design, it's not going to be easy keeping track of those labels you need to dynamically create. But since thats your current use case, then perhaps what you want to do is maintain a [Mutable Array](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of labels. That way you can create just as many as you need and still be able to share information across your methods (as an ivar in your class). So your class definition would have this (code stolen from @Macmade and updated):

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject {
     NSMutableArray * _labels; 
}  

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * labels;

- ( void )methodA; 
- ( void )methodB;
@end
```

In your methodA, you create new labels and add them to your array. In your methodB you locate a label and set its text property.

```
@implementation MyClass 

@synthesize labels = _labels;

- ( id ) init 
{ 
    if( ( self = [ super init ] ) ) {
              [self setLabels: [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 8];
    } 
} 

- ( void ) dealloc 
{ 
    [ self.labels release ]; 
    [ super dealloc ]; 
} 

- ( void ) methodA 
{ 
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
    [self.labels addObject: label];
} 

- ( void ) methodB 
{
    // You need to locate the label you work with. One way is by index, crude example below
    UILabel * theLabel = (UILabel * ) [self.labels objectAtIndex: 0];
    theLabel.text = @"Label 1"; 
} 

@end
```

You will need some good way of identifying what label you are dealing with -index is probably not the best. Ideally you would actually use an [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and store your labels keyed by their name.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access a function's local variable from another function. A local variable only exist when the function is called, and is *destroyed* when the function returns.

Use an instance variable for this.

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject
{
    UILabel * label1;
}

- ( void )methodA;
- ( void )methodB;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- ( id )init
{
    if( ( self = [ super init ] ) )
    {
        UILabel * label1 = [ [ UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame: CGRectZero ];
    }
}

- ( void )dealloc
{
    [ label1 release ];
    [ super dealloc ];
}

- ( void )methodA
{
    /* label1 is now a valid instance of UILabel */
}

- ( void )methodB
{
    label1.text = @"Label 1";
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If methodB is being called by methodA then pass it as a parameter.  If it is not then you should declare it in the header file.

This is about variable scope.  When the your method exists all variables declared inside are destroyed.  Obviously you can use the return keyword to pass values back but you will not be able to use the variable by the name you declared it with in methodA.

In this case it looks like you need to add this to your header file:

```
UILabel *label1;
```

When you do this you will be able to allocate and initialise the variable in methodA and then set its value in method B.  Just remember that the first line of methodA will become.

```
label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By defining label1 in your header file.

Answer (score 0):

Either with a parameter:

```
- (void)methodA {
    ...
    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self methodB:label1];
}

- (void)methodB:(UILabel *)label1 {
    label1.text = "Label 1";
}
```

Or by creating a object attribute in the @interface (see attributes in an object-c guide). There is no other good way.

Answer (score 0):

An other gimmick I sometimes use is to create a variable in the app delegate and then each function can access then modify the variable... I don't usually use it in your case but it should normally work... Hope it helped ! If needed, don't hesitate to ask for more elements.

CU !